# C char[] and *char

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have an issue with C strings. I have array `char char_array[256] = {0}`.

I had fulfilled this array with char elements. When I print these elements `printf("%c", char_array[0]);`, `printf("%c", char_array[1]);` and etc, the values are correct. But when I try to print `printf("%s", char_array);`, it prints nothing...

Also I have function `void function(char* char_pointer)`. I am trying to return data `strcpy(char_pointer, char_array)`. But it returns nothing...

Please, help me, how to return data from function, that later, outside function, I could print `printf("%s", char_pointer_from_function)`?

UPDATE:

Function:

```
void unmarshal_packet(char *packet)
{
    char packet_size_string [10] = {0};
    char unmarshaled_data [2000] = {0};
    int counter = 0;

    while (packet[counter] != ':' && counter < strlen(packet))
    {
        packet_size_string[counter] = packet[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    counter = strlen(packet_size_string) + 1;

    for (counter; counter < strlen(packet); counter++)
    {
        if ((packet[counter] != '\r') && (packet[counter] != '\n'))
        {
            unmarshaled_data[counter - (strlen(packet_size_string) + 1)] = packet[counter];
        }
    }

    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[0]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[1]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[2]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[3]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[4]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[5]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[6]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[7]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[8]);
    // printf("%c", unmarshaled_data[9]);

    printf("%s", unmarshaled_data);

    unmarshaled_data[counter - (strlen(packet_size_string) + 1)] = '\0';

    strcpy(packet, unmarshaled_data); 
}
```

Function call:

```
strcpy(buffer, " \nWellcome to Yes / No game server! \n");
unmarshal_packet(buffer);
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: @Jacob Jones Please show the relevant code.

Comment: `%s` means to print a *string* , which is a series of non-null characters followed by a null character. It'll stop printing if it finds null character, and also you may get surprising output for non-printable characters (e.g. carriage return)

Comment: I have updated my post with further details.

Comment: You've got your answer and we don't need more updates. You didn't null terminate your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are sequences of non-NULL (ASCII value 0) characters, followed by such a character indicating the end of the string.  If, for example, your first character where a NULL, that would represent an *empty* string, and so nothing would be printed.  Not knowing what you put in your array before printing, I cannot say what should be printed.